# WooCommerce: How to hide prices in customer-on-hold-order Mail, but not in other Mails?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to customize WooCommerce and hide all Pricing Information in the customer-on-hold-order Mail, but not in the other Mails.

I have already copied Mail Templates to /mytheme/woocommerce/emails earlier, and because they are already modified, i copied

email-order-items.php and
email-order-details.php

to

email-order-items-noprice.php and
email-order-details-noprice.php

...and modified them to show no price.

Now I believe I must change customer-on-hold-order.php to call my new noprice files

In this file I can see

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

I wish that I could just change the line to

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details_noprice', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

...but then nothing happens. It is probably because the hook 'woocommerce_email_order_details_noprice' does not exist.

What must I do to create this hook, and where?
Or is there a better solution to this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Just do as follows to achieve your requirements -

1. First copied `email-order-details.php` and `email-order-items.php` templates in `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/` as you have already done. But dont needs to renamed it.
2. Now in your template named `email-order-details.php` replace follows -

`<th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>`

with follows -

`<?php if( $order->get_status() !== 'on-hold' ) : ?>
<th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
<?php endif; ?>`

3. In your template named `email-order-items.php` replace follows -

`<td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ) ); ?>
        </td>`

with follows -

`<?php if( $order->get_status() !== 'on-hold' ) : ?>
<td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
    <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ) ); ?>
</td>
<?php endif; ?>`

Thats it.

Comment: Ah, ok, you are checking the order Status. Good Idea.
if( $order->get_status() !== 'on-hold' ) ...
But what about the other mail being sent on a new order...the one that the ShopAdmin receives to notify him of a new order? This has then, so i believe, also the status 'on-hold' and will have hidden prices, but here there must be prices displayed. What do you think?

Comment: Then just modify the logic as  - `if( $sent_to_admin ){
     // add price block
    }elseif (!$sent_to_admin && $order->get_status() !== 'on-hold' ) {
     // add price block
    }`

Comment: Checked with echo $order->get_status(): Both Mails have "on-hold".Will check your new solution

Comment: Just implement the above commented logic it should work.